# Data Type - socklen_t, sa_family_t

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, socklen-t

I'm building a simple socket web server using the [sys/socket.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) lib, and I came across the `socklen_t` and `sa_family_t` data types and am a bit confused on what their actual purpose is.

Definition:

- `sa_family_t` - unsigned integer type.
- `socklen_t` - an unsigned opaque integer type of length of at least 32-bits.

Now I understand that the `<sys/socket>` lib declares three structures (`sockaddr`,`msghdr`,`cmsghdr`)  which contain members that declare these data  types.

- `sa_family_t   sa_family       address family`
- `socklen_t     msg_namelen     size of address`
- `socklen_t     msg_controllen  ancillary data buffer len`
- `socklen_t     cmsg_len        data byte count, including the cmsghdr`

But why create new data types, why not just use an `unsigned int` data type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By declaring specific types for these fields, it decouples them from a particular representation like `unsigned int`.

Different architectures can be free to define different sizes for these fields, and code that uses these specific types doesn't need to worry about how big an `int` is on a given machine.

Comment: Ok yea thats makes sense... so basically when it says "at least" 32-bits, it's implying that it "could" be greater, and that would be arch based, correct?

Comment: Correct.  Similarly for `size_t` as well.

Comment: Cool perfect, and makes sense why it recommends not using anything higher than `2^32-1` if you want to port it between 32/64-bit systems. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it!